# Entry module not found on migrated Angular app

Tags: angular, webpack, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I tried migrating an Angular 7.0.3 web app to a NativeScript 6.0.3 project by adding the `@nativescript/schematics` (following [this guide](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-sharing/migrating-a-web-project)).

After this, I've had some trouble with `ng serve`: had to get rid of 'src/' in front of the items in the `files` array in `src/tsconfig.app.json` and fix all my imports that were using the path "@app/" to "app/". It is now building the web app correctly again.

Now, I'm trying to `tns run android` but I get some webpack errors and warnings:

```
Searching for devices...
Preparing project...

webpack is watching the files…


Insufficient number of arguments or no entry found.
Alternatively, run 'webpack(-cli) --help' for usage info.

Hash: a1740daac85938c772ac
Version: webpack 4.8.3
Time: 60ms
Built at: 2019-08-13 14:42:39

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/

ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'D:\work\transat_dev'
Executing webpack failed with exit code 0.
```

Particularly this bit: `ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in ...`.

Any idea on what could cause this error?

Comment: I have this same issue after adding`@nativescript/schematics` to an existing Angular app in an nx workspace. Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I didn't investigate more on this issue as I have been charged with other projects.